# Wordpress xmlrpc python check if post title exists

Tags: python, wordpress, python-3.x, xml-rpc

Making website for my town library using wordpress. The site will have several thousand posts, one for each book. I'm trying to get it so if that if a post with the same title already exists, it prints out something to let me know before I post it.

I have this snippet of code but it's pretty old and the documentation for xmlrpc wordpress especially with python is very lax.

```
post_id=find_id(post.title)
if post_id:
    print ("Sorry, we already have such a post" + post_id)
else:
    pass
```

This is the rest of my publishing code.

```
#client info#
wp = Client(wp_url, wp_username, wp_password)

post = WordPressPost()
post.title = 'Dracula'
post.post_status = 'draft'
post.terms_names = {
  'post_format': ['book'],
  'category': [tag],

}


post.custom_fields = []
post.custom_fields.append({'key':'dp_desc','value':desc})
post.custom_fields.append({'key':'fifu_image_url','value':thumb})

wp.call(NewPost(post))
```

Sorry if the answer exists already, all that I've seen have been in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts

wp = Client(wp_url, wp_username, wp_password)
posts = wp.call(posts.GetPosts())
values = ','.join(str(v) for v in posts) # Changes list to a string
```

Then you can just check the string for matches.

```
if title in values:
    print('Post already exists!')
    continue
else:
    pass
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.